# Unbind onchange without triggering it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some controls each of which updates the others on change. To prevent recursion I had thought to unbind the onchange event at the start of the event handler (one handler is shared by the controls concerned) and then rebind it after updating the dependents. All controls involved are tagged with the DateBoundControl class for convenient reference, and I have verified that the expected controls are returned by the jquery expression.

The problem code looks like this:

```
function onDateBoundChange(evt) {
  $(".DateBoundControl").change();
  //do stuff to other controls that use this change handler
  $(".DateBoundControl").change(onDateBoundChange);
}
```

However, `$(".DateBoundControl").change();` seems to *trigger* the change event.

Is there something I've missed? Is there some flaw in my attempt to unbind the handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, $(".DateBoundControl").change(); seems to trigger the change event.

As the documentation [clearly states](http://api.jquery.com/change/), that's exactly what it's supposed to do.

You're looking for the [`off()` method](http://api.jquery.com/off/), which unbinds an event.

Comment: While you were writing this, I was busily discovering that the documentation clearly states etc. However, thank you for 'off' this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
function onDateBoundChange(evt) {
  $(".DateBoundControl").unbind('change', onDateBoundChange);
  //do stuff to other controls that use this change handler
  $(".DateBoundControl").bind('change', onDateBoundChange);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think this is also a good answer however SLaks' answer is *exactly* what I was looking for. Can't accept both so +1 for you.